# Error while running react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

***Error:***

> Cannot find module 'webpack/schemas/WebpackOptions.json'

My ***webpack.config.js*** looks like this -

```
var config = {
entry: './main.js',
output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: 'index.js',
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: which version of webpack-dev-server are you using? got same problem and it's just working with "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1" for me now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry to revive this but I had a different solution..

I had used

```
npm install -g webpack-cli
npm install webpack
```

The issue seems to happen for me because the CLI is expecting webpack to be installed globally as well? To fix this I instead installed both CLI and webpack locally

```
npm uninstall -g webpack-cli
npm install webpack webpack-cli
```

In my package.json I just added:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli",
  "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --watch",
}
```

Then whenever I need to use webpack I just use `npm run build` or `npm run watch`.

And boom everything magically worked!

This is an issue with Webpack though I believe. I will be reporting it and I'll try to update this answer with it's progress.

UPDATE (2018/05/11): I have reported the issue to the Webpack team on a task I believe may be related. Follow/contribute here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/299#issuecomment-388390143

UPDATE (2018/05/23): There is apparently a fix now and the issue should be resolved in the next version of webpack-cli. As of this writing though it seems to still not be resolved yet in the public release version of webpack-cli.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
npm install webpack
```

Then create a script in your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
  },
```

Then run `npm run build` instead of running `webpack` directly.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should need to run in your existing app

```
yarn install
```

or

```
npm install
```

It may fix your issue.

Comment: I did run npm install. I am still facing the same error.

Comment: Error - Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/schemas/WebpackOptions.json'

Comment: which node version you are using, I am using node v8.9.4. and in node_modules\webpack\schemas path i get webpackOptionsSchema.json file not any WebpackOptions.json.

Comment: I am using v8.11.1 node. I don't see schemas under node_modules/webpack.

Comment: Try blowing away your entire node_modules folder and running yarn again.

Comment: It may seem issue in your app may be, try to create new app and check there is this issuecoming or not and check node_modules\webpack\schemas exists or not. Go to [link](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by simply adding webpack locally (yarn add --dev webpack). I had it installed globally but when I ran it in the console, gave me this error.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the global version of webpack & webpack-cli for now. This affects local installations, as webpack and the cli are split and they can't resolve each other

Answer (score 0):

in windows, run cmd in **administrator** mode, then

```
npm install -g  webpack webpack-cli
```